# Installing snipping tool in centos6

Tags: linux, terminal, centos6

How can I install any snipping tools in CentOS? Is there any terminal commands available in CentOS to install snipping tools? Because no direct downloads available in CentOS only way is through terminal commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install snipping tool `shutter` using

`yum install shutter`

command in centOS. You should have root permission to install it.

Comment: When I tried first a repository was missing and after i installed the epel repository and then used your command, now shutter got installed. Thank you!!